# Python doesn't commit data to SQLite database

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

This code should insert and save these two records to my database every time I run this code, but it doesn't work.

There is no errors, everything works fine except commiting changes to database and I don't know why.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('SQLite_Python.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS expenses;""")
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE expenses (
            name text,
            amount text,
            date_of_expense text,
            category text,
            notes text
            )""")

def insert_expense(exp):
    with conn:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO expenses VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", 
            (exp.name, exp.amount, exp.date_of_expense, exp.category, exp.notes))


def get_all_expenses():
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM expenses")
    return c.fetchall()

exp1 = Expense('apple', '5.50', '02:12:1202','food', '-')
exp2 = Expense('orange', '9.90', '05:02:1892', 'food', '-')

insert_expense(exp1)
insert_expense(exp2)

exps = get_expense_by_category('food')
print(exps)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

My goal is to save records to database and when I open this database again, I want to see old records.

Comment: How do you expect to see old records if you have "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS expenses" each time ?

Comment: jeeez, I don't know why I didn't notice that.. thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS expenses" ;)